# I have a route that works when I use localhost:3000, but breaks when I use the live app on gcloud's app engine?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

The route uses the DELETE method, which I was able to use in nodejs with the use of the method-override npm package. I can use curl for my GET and POST routes fine, but for the DELETE route in particular, when I change the url from `http://localhost:3000/` to `http://nameofapp.appspot.com/` in my cURL call, I get a "Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1" in return.

I looked at the route on the dashboard, and it's shown under "client errors" and it shows an error rate of 100% but doesn't give me any more information than that. It is always successful with localhost.

Any ideas??

Comment: potentially related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398012/how-to-use-http-method-delete-on-google-app-engine

Comment: if your request has a body try, as a test only, a request with no budy, just to see if you get the same error - deletes with body are quite controversial. Personally I would try to achieve the delete ops using post requests.