# webclient upload file methods

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

It seems that webclient supports PUT and POST uploading. Is there any difference?

Comment: See the first answer here:  [What are the best/common RESTful url verbs and actions?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/256349/1122029

Answer (score 3):

Yes, one sends a [PUT](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6) to the server, one sends a [POST](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5).  In theory, PUT means "enclosed entity [should] be stored under the supplied Request-URI", and POST means "the entity enclosed in the request [i]s a new subordinate of the resource identified by the Request-URI"

But in practice, it's up to the server what to do.

Comment: I always see POST for HTTP and PUT for FTP.

Comment: POST and PUT are both HTTP methods.  Separately, there are PUT and MPUT FTP commands.