# jQuery ajax url parameters drupal server

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, drupal

I'm trying to send inline parameters to a rest server:

```
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: this.apiPath + '/disp',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: 'disp_id=' +  disp_id,
    success: callback
  });
```

Is there a way to pass parameters to a jQuery ajax?
I've tried in a lot of manners but no way...

```
data: {disp_id: disp_id},
data: "{disp_id:" + '"' + disp_id + '"}',
data: JSON.stringify({disp_id: disp_id}),
```

Always the same answer: "401 Unauthorized: Missing required argument disp_id".

The only way I achieved this is with:

```
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: this.apiPath + '/disp?disp_id=' + disp_id,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: callback
  });
```

**Extra details:**

this.apiPath = `http://localhost/public_html/svc/disps`

On the server side (drupal) I've defined the following hook_services_resources:

```
  $services_resources['disps']['actions']['disp'] = array(
    'help'                    => t('Retrieves the cue of objects for a given id'),
    'file'                    => array('type' => 'inc', 'module' => 'disps', 'name' => 'resources/disps.resource', ),
    'callback'                => '_disps_resource_dispositivos',
    'access callback'         => 'disps_can_view_disp',
    'access arguments'        =>  array(NULL),
    'access arguments append' => FALSE,
    'args'                    => array(
      array(
        'name'          => 'disp_id',
        'type'          => 'string',
        'description'   => '',
        'source'        => array('param' => 'disp_id', ),
        'optional'      => FALSE,
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Comment: If it's a REST server, I'd suggest using RESTful URLs

Comment: Great! Yes, that made me rethink... I'm going to see if with GET is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Madbreaks (+1 for it), moved to RESTful URLs (see [What are the best/common RESTful url verbs and actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256349/what-are-the-best-common-restful-url-verbs-and-actions) and [How to create REST URLs without verbs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619152/how-to-create-rest-urls-without-verbs)):

```
  $services_resources['user']['relationships']['disps'] = array(
    'help'                    => t('Retrieves the disps for a given user'),
    'file'                    => array('type' => 'inc', 'module' => 'disps', 'name' => 'resources/disps.resource', ),
    'callback'                => '_disps_user_dispositivos',
    'access callback'         => '_disps_user_dispositivos_access',
    'access callback file'    => array('type' => 'inc', 'module' => 'disps', 'name' => 'resources/disps.resource', ),
    'access arguments'        => array('view'),
    'access arguments append' => TRUE,
    'args'                    => array(
      array(
        'name'          => 'account',
        'type'          => 'string',
        'description'   => 'The account to retrieve the cue from',
        'source'        => array('path' => 0, ),
        'optional'      => FALSE,
      ),
      array(
        'name'          => 'disp_id',
        'type'          => 'string',
        'description'   => 'The disp_id to retrieve the cue from',
        'source'        => array('param' => 'disp_id', ),
        'optional'      => FALSE,
      ),
    ),
  );
```

so now in the js there is

```
userAPI.disps_cue= function (disp_id, user, callback) {
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: this.apiPath + 'user/' + user + '/disps',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {disp_id: disp_id,},
    success: callback,
  });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery("#getCue").submit(function() {
    jQuery("#msg").html("Enviando datos..."));
    userAPI.disps_cue(jQuery("input:[name=disp_id]").val(), function(data) {
      jQuery("#result").append(CreateTableView(data, "box-table-b"));
      jQuery("#msg").html("Ok!");
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery.post(this.apiPath + '/disp', {'disp_id':  disp_id}, callback);
```

Comment: Same result: Error 401 and the parametres are not set as parametres, just as POST data