# RESTful API design: best way to CRUD lightweight connections?

Tags: web-services, api, facebook-graph-api, rest, github-api

(Pardon the question title; hard to summarize this question.)

On Facebook, you `like` things. On Twitter, you `follow` people. On GitHub, you also `follow` people and `star` repos and gists.

All of these cases are pretty similar: those connections are lightweight, not really "resources" themselves. E.g. none of those three APIs expose public IDs for such connections.

This raises the question: **what's the "best" (in terms of REST) way to expose an API for creating/querying/deleting those connections?**

---

**Facebook** does [[1](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)]:

- `GET /:id/likes` to query an object's likes (more precisely, the users that like that object)
- `POST /:id/likes` to like something (on behalf of the auth'ed user; no req body needed)
- `DELETE /:id/likes` to unlike something (on behalf of the auth'ed user)

The querying and creating make sense, but the `DELETE` is a bit "unRESTful", because you're not actually deleting the `/:id/likes` resource (an array of users that like that object).

This discrepancy shows itself in another case [[2](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/540/)]:

- `GET /me/likes/:id` to query whether you like something

So querying your connection is querying a totally different resource than creating or deleting it.

---

**GitHub** leans to the `/me/likes/:id` style for following users and starring *repos* [[3](http://developer.github.com/v3/activity/starring/)]:

(Note that GitHub's `/user` represents the auth'ed user, like Facebook's `/me`.)

- `GET /user/starred/:owner/:repo` for querying whether you have a repo starred (returns 204 or 404, no body either way)
- `PUT /user/starred/:owner/:repo` for starring a repo (no body needed in request)
- `DELETE /user/starred/:owner/:repo` for unstarring a repo

This is much more consistent, but unfortunately this separates individual "stars" from the group:

- `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/stargazers` to query the users who've starred a repo

---

**GitHub**, interestingly, uses a different style for starring *gists* [[4](http://developer.github.com/v3/gists/)]:

- `GET /gists/:id/star` for querying whether you have a gist starred
- `PUT /gists/:id/star` for starring a gist
- `DELETE /gists/:id/star` for unstarring a gist

This keeps the starring action with the gist resource, like Facebook, rather than the user resource.

GitHub doesn't publicly expose *gists'* stargazers, but presumably it'd be e.g.:

- `GET /gists/:id/stargazers` to query the users who've starred a gist

While "stargazers" is indeed a different resource/name than "star", the names are similar and clearly related, and they're both on the same resource.

The only downside I can think of to this is naming the resource. Something like `star` works, but actions like `follow` or `like` are trickier.

---

(Not bothering to include the Twitter API as an example since it's hardly RESTful.)

There's clearly no perfectly RESTful API for creating/querying/deleting things that aren't proper resources, but are there other pros/cons I'm not seeing, or other styles to consider?

Thanks!

Comment: how does your url structure look for 3 states, like, dislike and undoing the vote (like or dislike)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I liked about the `/me/likes/:id` style is that the likes *do* feel like individual, addressable resources -- e.g. they have individual IDs (that happen to be the same as the things I'm liking).

GitHub's *repo* API uses this nicely for creating/querying/deleting "star" connections to repos, but there's a discrepancy for fetching *all* "star" connections for a given repo.

Perhaps the discrepancy could be addressed by changing the way you address these connections: instead of relying solely on the object ID, use the (auth'ed) user's ID too. E.g.:

- `GET /:owner/:repo/stargazers` to query all the users who've starred this repo
- `GET /:owner/:repo/stargazers/:id` to query whether user `:id` has the repo starred -- this can be the auth'ed user by specifying `me`!
- `PUT /:owner/:repo/stargazers/me` to star a repo -- this'll only work for the auth'ed user
- `DELETE /:owner/:repo/stargazers/me` to unstar a repo -- ditto

Now all the resources/actions are together, the actions are consistent, and naming is easy.

**Edit:** Another benefit of this approach is that you can easily and efficiently query whether *other* users like/follow/star an object, as well.

**Edit:** But a downside is that the resources aren't technically correct anymore -- `GET .../stargazers` returns a list of *users*, but `GET .../stargazers/:id` returns a connection, not a user. Oh well?

*[Edited again to support passing `me` as the `:id` here too.]*

Answer (score 0):

I think

DELETE /:id/likes to unlike something (on behalf of the auth'ed user)

makes sense, since the like would have a compound key of the liked object's id and your user id, so specifying an id is just redundant when your authenticated login already tells who you are, and you don't even have permission to delete other user's likes anyway.

Explicitly specifying this (as suggested by Aseem Kishore) like

DELETE /:id/likes/me

...might be a bit more clear.