# Correct REST naming

Tags: rest

Say I have an application that has accounts, I could represent them as rest resources like:

```
/accounts   //single account
/accounts/{id}    //a specific account
```

1) If an account has an account status, is this the correct way of referencing it?

```
/accounts/{id}/status
```

2) How do I represent searches in REST, say I want to search for and account starting with "ABC"?

Comment: There are many good answers and at least as many bad ones. There is definitely no definitive answer. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: There is no correct REST "naming". REST is not a set of rules governing how to name URLs. It is a style of architecture. You could use either `/accounts/3` or `/accounts?id=3` or `/3/accounts` and be equally valid. Your question is like asking, "How many dots should I use to draw a face in [pointillism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointillism)?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If an account has an account status, is this the correct way of
>   referencing it?

Perhaps, if the account status is a fully fledged data object in its own right. If it's a simple scalar value you can consider using a parameter to constrain the value returned from `/accounts/{id}`, for example `GET /accounts/{id}?field=status`.

> How do I represent searches in REST, say I want to search for and account starting with "ABC"?

With a URL parameter:

```
GET /accounts/?search=ABC*
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing nouns and verbs in your URLs which generally speaking is not a RESTFul approach. [In this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256349/what-are-the-best-common-restful-url-verbs-and-actions) they talk about the differences of representing nouns and verbs in your urls. Searching though is a different beast and having tried this a few different ways I am preferring to follow the approach of making a search its own url. One reason for this is to get caching on GET requests which you can do with making the URL centered around searching. Query params don't get cached so that is another argument against using them for them as an argument on the end of our GET request. [This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207477/restful-url-design-for-search) talks more about the approach that I like to use.

Comment: I don't think I am mixing nouns and verbs because status is a field of account.