# laravel route parameters with post routes vs post parameters

Tags: php, laravel

Should route parameters only be used for get/delete requests?
A user can join a challenge and I want to have an API endpoint for that.

Is this ok:

```
Route::post('/challenge/{challenge}/join', 'UserController@joinChallenge');
```

or should I rather pass the challenge id in the post body?

Comment: what is your "challenge"? is it a public string?

Comment: the challenge is a uuid

Comment: make it a slug(friendier url), see my answer below

Comment: It doesn't matter if the users won't see it or it doesn't require SEO inspection.

Comment: It's you who will see if the challenge uuid can be seen or not if it's ok to expose it to people then use URL parapeter else use a hidden field in the form !!

Answer (score 2):

POST is a perfec solution:
"Good Web design" requires non-idempotent actions to be sent via POST. This is a non-idempotent action(It has side effects, it modifyes the state of  the DB).

Server logs don't record POST parameters, but they record urls. It's easier to look something through the logs with that design in your scenario.

idempotent:
http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/idempotency.html

Answer (score 2):

It is ok

better way:

```
Route::post('/challenge/{challengeId}', 'UserController@joinChallenge');
```

don't forget to catch id in your controller

`function joinChallenge(Request $request, $challangeId)`

please see the reference below

[What are the best/common RESTful url verbs and actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256349/what-are-the-best-common-restful-url-verbs-and-actions/256359#256359)

Answer (score 0):

you can pass parametres inside your url but you need to take accept this param by your method  `joinChallenge(Request $request, $challenge)`